# .NET xElement error reconciliation (html entity name to its numeric character reference conversion)

Tags: html, .net, xml

I need to parse HTML into an xElement. I understand this solution isn't very forgiving for malformed HTML. Which is fine since I want to trap to invalid HTML anyways. However, I don't want the XElement.Parse() method to fail whenever I run into an HTML entity.

I'm wondering if there is something built into the .NET framework which will convert named HTML entities to a numeric character reference.

This works, But I really don't want to do this for every entity.

```
Public Function GetEntityReplacementList() As IDictionary(Of String, String)
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html
    Dim _dictonary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    _dictonary.Add("&nbsp;", "&#160;") ' " " non-breaking space
    _dictonary.Add("&lt;", "&#60;") '<  less than
    _dictonary.Add("&gt;", "&#62;") '>  greater than
    _dictonary.Add("&amp;", "&#38;") '&     ampersand
    _dictonary.Add("&cent;", "&#162;") '¢   cent
    _dictonary.Add("&pound;", "&#163;") '£  pound
    _dictonary.Add("&yen;", "&#165;") '¥    yen
    _dictonary.Add("&euro;", "&#8364;") '€  euro
    _dictonary.Add("&copy;", "&#169;") '©   copyright
    _dictonary.Add("&reg;", "&#174;") '® registered trademark
    _dictonary.Add("&lsquo;", "&#8216;") ' single quote
    _dictonary.Add("&rsquo;", "&#8217;") ' single quote
    _dictonary.Add("&ldquo;", "&#8220;") ' Double quote
    _dictonary.Add("&rdquo;", "&#8221;") ' Double quote
    _dictonary.Add("&bull;", "&#8226;") ' Bullet
    _dictonary.Add("&ccedil;", "&#199;")
    _dictonary.Add("&euml;", "&#199;")
    _dictonary.Add("&eacute;", "&#233;")
    _dictonary.Add("&mdash;", "&#8212;")
    _dictonary.Add("&egrave;", "&#200;")
    _dictonary.Add("&aacute;", "&#225;")
    _dictonary.Add("&ndash;", "&#8211;")
    Return _dictonary
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function CreateXElementWithEntityReplacements(p_xml As String) As XElement


    For Each _pair In GetEntityReplacementList()
        p_xml = Regex.Replace(p_xml, _pair.Key, _pair.Value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Next

    Return XElement.Parse(p_xml)

End Function
```

Comment: Have you considered using HtmlAgilitypack instead?

Comment: I have, I'm trying to avoid third party libraries for the moment.

Comment: Anyone?? I'm not finding anything in the MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to run into lots of problems here.  As much as you want to capture invalid HTML, there is valid HTML that is invalid XML - for example, `<br>` is valid HTML but invalid XML.

However, if you're confident that your solution **only** needs to parse HTML that is also valid XML, you could just add the correct entity definitions to the top of your document string and it will parse properly from there out.  For example, you could add the following to your html string:

```
<!DOCTYPE documentElement[
  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#16;">
]><a href = 'blah'>&nbsp; &lt; &amp;</a>
```

And this will parse as valid HTML.  You can get a list of the entities from the HTML DTDs, available here:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-special.ent
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-symbol.ent

You could skip `lt`, `gt`, and `amp` - these are valid XML entities anyway.  Alternatively, you could take that list and refactor it into your dictionary.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. You're absolutely correct. I'm writing an Epub reader, so I also have to account for malformed html as well. I don't think the xElement class is the way to go anymore.

Comment: I know you said you want to avoid third party libs, but this is pretty much exactly what HtmlAgilityPack is written for.  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com